# Using UNION sub query inside of NOT IN MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to use a union sub query inside not null in MySQL. The query is shown below.

```
SELECT s.student_id
     , s.student_name
  FROM students` s
 WHERE s.student_id NOT IN (
    SELECT student_id
      FROM free_students
     UNION
    SELECT student_id
    FROM paid_students
)
```

If the UNION sub query returns null the query results also becomes null. How to handle these kind of situations?

Comment: I think it's a mistake to store students in separate table tables in this way. Surely it's better to have a single table with a column identifying their status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an exists clause, two of them actually:

```
SELECT s.student_id, s.student_name
FROM students s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM free_students fs WHERE s.student_id = fs.student_id) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM paid_students ps WHERE s.student_id = ps.student_id);
```

Comment: Why there is SELECT 1?

Comment: @Camille I can't explain the syntax behind `EXISTS` in just a comment, or even several comments.  Long story short, the syntax I used is checking that, for each `student_id` in the `students` table, we cannot find a matching `student_id` in either or the other two tables.